# After 30 min in Windows-8.1 Pro the computer automaticaly powers down

Tags: windows-8.1, freeze

I have a problem with Windows-8.1 Pro: it automatically powers down after 30 min.  At 25 min it freezes up then powers down.  I run a dual boot system with Windows 7. It doesn't happen in Windows 7.  It started after I upgraded to Windows 8.1 update.  How do I fix this?

Comment: After the next power down, make note of the time. Power it up and check eventviewer, and see what is triggering the shut down.

Comment: Also could be a faulty driver. Try running in safe mode.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be quite scheduled. Have you had a look at "Search > Control Panel > Power Options?"

I'm aware the options only offer Sleep or Monitor Off, but you may get some idea of what is going on. Let us know if you see any 25 or 30 min selection on the "Put the computer to sleep" line.

Regards,
dkp